# Netezza Formatting Functions

Tags: sql, format, number-formatting, type-conversion, netezza

I've imported a somewhat large set of data, with, at times, an odd number format (e.g., 12,345.01- and 1,945.001-), and I am trying to 'fix' it.

The data was imported as `VARCHAR(20)`

My solution:

```
to_number(BadNumCol, 'S999G999G999D999')

input: 10426.95 ;261.000 ;33.93-

outputs:42695.00 ;261.000 ; 3.93

the output is NUMERIC(12,3)

desired output: 10426.95 ; 261.000 ; -33.93
```

What's going on here?  What am I missing/not understanding in my ignorance?

And, how do I *fix* these ~400 Million data elements?

Comment: The format for your sample input data in your "solution" section is different than the format for the sample input data in the first line of your question.  One has group separators, and one doesn't. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ther are two issues that I see here.

In the case of the sample input data from the "solution" section of you data, none of the sample input data has group separators, so the group separators you are specifying in your TO_NUMBER function is mismatched.

Also, you are specifyng a sign character anchored to the beginning of the string, when your data has a trailing minus instead.

The most appropriate conversion format string I can infer from your sample input data is: '999999999D999MI'

```
select * from num_test;
 BADNUMCOL
-----------
 261.000
 10426.95
 33.93-
(3 rows)

select to_number(BadNumCol,'999999999D999MI')::NUMERIC(12,3) GoodNumCol from num_test;
 GOODNUMCOL
------------
  10426.950
    -33.930
    261.000
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I knew it would be straightforward.  The MI is more like a pointer to tell the current schema where to find the minus (if needed)?

Comment: I might have messed up my edit to my comment above.  I understand now.  The formatting is more of a means to communicate how to interpret the input rather than explaining how to format the output.  Now the documentation makes more sense.  Thank you..

Comment: You're right.  The MI token tells it that there might be a minus sign at the end.  Technically we could have put the S at the end which might have made it more flexible, but MI was what I use by default because I never see plus signs at the end of the string.

Comment: If that works for you, don't forget to mark the question as answered.  And welcome to SO